# How would i split up 2 values in parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, split, coordinates, parentheses

So, I'm working on a python script that will auto click at the coordinates of set pixels. I'm encountering an issue where I need to split up two values in normal parentheses.
Example:

```
(1023, 503)
```

Is there any way to even split this up into two variables or is it impossible?

Comment: That value in parentheses is called a `tuple` and it supports unpacking: `a, b = (1023, 503)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these values in parenthesis are called `tuples`, and they can be unpacked,

**Example:**

```
>>> value1,value2 = (1,0)
>>> value1
1
>>> value2
0
```

in your case:

```
variable1,variable2 = (1023, 503)
```